# Hot to run selenium script on desktops of differernt resolutions

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am working as a Test engineer. We are using desktops of different size in our project. While executing the selenium script, the application does not fit on the screen. I want the application to fit in the screen. by using Dimension methods and some chrome add-ons we have tried but no use.
I hope I will get the solution here.